# Dart multi threading

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of employee Numbers : List employees=[10,11,12,13]
and I have a method:

```
void calculatePay(employeeNumber){//do some calcs}
```

is there a way to run the calculatedPay() concurrently for each employee in dart

Comment: What kind of operation are you going to do on each number? If the logic is mostly async (e.g. waiting for IO operations like network or disk) or are the waiting time going to be CPU intensive operations?

Comment: i am performing some basic calculations that return an employee pay for each employee

Comment: Ok, then try doing it without concurrency and see if it works fine for you. I don't think the overhead spawning multiple threads, and then collect the results, are going to be worth it.

Comment: the calculations parameter takes an enormous amount of time to process so if i need to minimize that

Comment: Well, then you are no longer "performing some basic calculations". That was why I asked you about if you was CPU bound or IO bound... But since you don't give any context about your issue, then the only thing I can recommend you looking into is: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html

Comment: okay let me put it this way,i have like 10 000 employees I want to calculate their net salary so, to calculate each employee's pay the system has to perform like 600 calculations that are predefined and these calculations have to run for each employee  because they determine the pay

Comment: Does the calculations involve server calls or are all needed information already inside the app?

Comment: yes they do involve server calls,

Answer (score -1):

**Dart multi threading?**

No you can not multi thread as Dart/Flutter is single threaded

however you can execute code while you are waiting on a method to complete by creating an asynchronous method, however in your instance this is not going to be of any significant benefit in terms of speeding up the execution of your specific method